# How to start remote transection in OCPP server using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iot, ocpp

We have created OCPP server using node js with help of [ocpp-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ocpp-rpc) and we got web socket connection from OCPP server here is the my sample code

```
const { RPCServer, createRPCError } = require('ocpp-rpc');

const server = new RPCServer({
  protocols: ['ocpp1.6'], // server accepts ocpp1.6 subprotocol
  strictMode: true,       // enable strict validation of requests & responses
 });

server.auth((accept, reject, handshake) => {
// accept the incoming client
accept({
    // anything passed to accept() will be attached as a 'session' property of the client.
    sessionId: 'XYZ123'
});
});

server.on('client', async (client) => {
console.log(`${client.session.sessionId} connected!`); // `XYZ123 connected!`

// create a specific handler for handling BootNotification requests
client.handle('BootNotification', ({params}) => {
    console.log(`Server got BootNotification from ${client.identity}:`, params);

    // respond to accept the client
    return {
        status: "Accepted",
        interval: 300,
        currentTime: new Date().toISOString()
    };
});

// create a specific handler for handling Heartbeat requests
client.handle('Heartbeat', ({params}) => {
    console.log(`Server got Heartbeat from ${client.identity}:`, params);

    // respond with the server's current time.
    return {
        currentTime: new Date().toISOString()
    };
});

// create a specific handler for handling StatusNotification requests
client.handle('StatusNotification', ({params}) => {
    console.log(`Server got StatusNotification from ${client.identity}:`, params);
    return {};
});

// create a wildcard handler to handle any RPC method
client.handle(({method, params}) => {
    // This handler will be called if the incoming method cannot be handled elsewhere.
    console.log(`Server got ${method} from ${client.identity}:`, params);

    // throw an RPC error to inform the server that we don't understand the request.
    throw createRPCError("NotImplemented");
});
});

await server.listen(3000);
```

now My question is how to start remote transaction from mobile app ? should i need to call my own OCPP server ? and how i will get data from the charging station point. as per our need we are adding node js OCPP server link to the **ABB** charging station config. please help if there any public repo or any blog or any sample code is available.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an OCPP call to a charging station using [ocpp-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ocpp-rpc), first you'll need a reference to the charging station's client connection. Adapting your example, here's one way you could set this up based on the charging station's OCPP identity:

```js
const allClients = new Map();

server.on('client', async (client) => {
    console.log(`${client.identity} connected!`);

    allClients.set(client.identity, client); // store client reference
});
```

Next, you need a way to trigger and make your call. Let's assume for a moment that you are using a http framework like express to create a REST API for this purpose. You could route a request like so:

```js
app.post('/charging-station/:identity/start-transaction', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        const client = allClients.get(req.params.identity);

        if (!client) {
            throw Error("Client not found");
        }

        const response = await client.call('RemoteStartTransaction', {
            connectorId: 1, // start on connector 1
            idTag: 'XXXXXXXX', // using an idTag with identity 'XXXXXXXX'
        });

        if (response.status === 'Accepted') {
            console.log('Remote start worked!');
        } else {
            console.log('Remote start rejected.');
        }

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Obviously if you're not using express, you'll need to adapt this to work for your situation.

Hope that gives you a good starting point to go from.

Comment: I have one more question what is the difference between "StartTransaction" & "RemoteStartTransaction" ? when should implement which event in our OCPP server

Comment: `RemoteStartTransaction` is called by when we command the cp externally such as api/csms. Then when cp receives the command, it calls `StartTransaction` internally along with transaction_id and the status received from `RemoteStartTransaction`. 

Another example would be when we start charging using RFID, that time, it starts internally no server call is made & only `StartTransaction` is called.

Below is the request params for `StartTransaction`

call_result.StartTransactionPayload(
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            id_tag_info={"status": "Accepted"}
        )

Comment: I am able to run this and achieve the result while running in local . However after hosting in aws ecs, it says client not found.Any reasons?